# Execute XQuery with BaseX

Tags: xml, xsd, xquery, basex

I am trying to use `BaseX` to run an `XQuery` with no success. I have tried typing commands like:

```
doc("Bookstore.xml")//Bookstore
//Bookstore
XQUERY[//Bookstore]
```

and i am getting these error messages:

```
Stopped at C:/tools/libxml/file, 1/32:
Unknown command: doc("Bookstore.xml")//Bookstore. Try HELP.

Stopped at C:/tools/libxml/file, 1/12:
Unknown command: //Bookstore. Try HELP.

Stopped at C:/tools/libxml/file, 1/20:
Unknown command: XQUERY[//Bookstore]. Try HELP.
```

whenever i try to hit <kbd>Execute Query</kbd>. How can i make this actually work? I am watching the [Stanford tutorials](https://class.coursera.org/db/lecture/20) but those commands that are showing there do not work on `BaseX`.

Below you can just see the `file` i am trying to query for educational purposes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--Bookstore with no DTD-->

<Bookstore>
   <Book ISBN="ISBN-0-13-713526-2" Price="85" Edition="3rd">
      <Title>A First Course in Database Systems</Title>
      <Authors>
         <Author>
            <First_Name>Jeffrey</First_Name>
            <Last_Name>Ullman</Last_Name>
         </Author>
         <Author>
            <First_Name>Jennifer</First_Name>
            <Last_Name>Widom</Last_Name>
         </Author>
      </Authors>
   </Book>
   <Book ISBN="ISBN-0-13-815504-6" Price="100">
      <Remark>
      Buy this book bundled with "A First Course" - a great deal!
      </Remark>
      <Title>Database Systems: The Complete Book</Title>
      <Authors>
         <Author>
            <First_Name>Hector</First_Name>
            <Last_Name>Garcia-Molina</Last_Name>
         </Author>
         <Author>
            <First_Name>Jeffrey</First_Name>
            <Last_Name>Ullman</Last_Name>
         </Author>
         <Author>
            <First_Name>Jennifer</First_Name>
            <Last_Name>Widom</Last_Name>
         </Author>
      </Authors>
   </Book>
</Bookstore>
```

**EDIT**

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're running BaseX commands, for example in the **BaseX command line client** or the GUI command input line, you have to prefix the query with the command `XQUERY`. BaseX commands are separated by whitespace from their parameters, so in your case, run any of

```
XQUERY //Bookstore
XQUERY doc('Bookstore.xml')//Bookstore
```

depending on whether the document (database) is already opened or not.

If you're using the **BaseX GUI**, you can also directly put the query into the query window, then you don't need the `XQUERY` command prefix at all and directly one of those (like above)

```
//Bookstore
//doc('Bookstore.xml')//Bookstore
```

[image: Command line and XQuery input in BaseX GUI]

---

Anyway: You'll probably want to use `/Bookstore` instead: at least if I'm guessing correctly and you want to query the root element, and not all `<Bookstore/>` elements in the whole document.

Comment: Thank you Jens the instructions that you have given to me work. I am on the `GUI` and i want to ask: there are two play buttons: 1)the first we can see in the pic you have posted and 2) a play button to the right of the box where we input commands. If i press the first play button it executes the query if i press the second it says unknown command. Do you know why?

Comment: I updated the image pointing to the "play buttons". The upper one is for commands, the lower one for queries. You should not load the XML file as a file, but create a database from it (using Database -> New). Where you put the XML document, you should write the query.

Comment: The [BaseX documentation](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Graphical_User_Interface) has some more information on how to use the GUI.

Comment: Thank you that freed me from a huge stalemate!

Comment: How would you execute an XQuery from a file?