# how to execute an XQuery from the BaseX console?

Tags: xml, xpath, command-line-interface, xquery, basex

How can I run an `XQuery` from `BaseX` in [standalone](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Standalone_Mode#Execute_a_Query) mode?

Using `BaseX` for simple read and query:

```
thufir@dur:~/basex$ 
thufir@dur:~/basex$ basex
[warning] /usr/bin/basex: Unable to locate /usr/share/java/jing.jar in /usr/share/java
BaseX 9.0.1 [Standalone]
Try 'help' to get more information.
> 
> LIST
Name  Resources  Size  Input Path                        
-------------------------------------------------------
note  1          5208  /home/thufir/basex/note.data.xml  

1 database(s).
> 
> OPEN note
Database 'note' was opened in 65.07 ms.
> 
> XQUERY db:open("note")//note
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
Query executed in 251.29 ms.
> 
> RUN query.note.db.xq
Resource "/home/thufir/query.note.db.xq" not found.
> 
> RUN query.note.xq
Resource "/home/thufir/query.note.xq" not found.
> 
> exit
Have a nice day.
thufir@dur:~/basex$
```

queries saved as `XQuery` files:

```
thufir@dur:~/basex$ 
thufir@dur:~/basex$ cat query.note.db.xq 

db:open("note")//note


thufir@dur:~/basex$ 
thufir@dur:~/basex$ cat query.note.xq 
//note
thufir@dur:~/basex$ 
thufir@dur:~/basex$ pwd
/home/thufir/basex
thufir@dur:~/basex$
```

Works [fine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24121601/262852) from the GUI:

[image: xquery]

Answer (score 2):

path fixed:

```
thufir@dur:~/basex$ 
thufir@dur:~/basex$ basex
[warning] /usr/bin/basex: Unable to locate /usr/share/java/jing.jar in /usr/share/java
BaseX 9.0.1 [Standalone]
Try 'help' to get more information.
> 
> RUN basex/query.note.db.xq
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
Query "query.note.db.xq" executed in 472.97 ms.
> 
> exit
Enjoy life.
thufir@dur:~/basex$
```

(Thanks to Christian Gruen for confirming it was a path problem.)